# Calculate difference between to unix epoch date times?

Tags: php, unix, epoch

I need to be able to find out the difference between two unix epoch times.

I am trying this at the moment

```
$interval = $nextFile-$firstFile;
```

($nextFile would equal "1452182820", $firstFile would equal "1452004380")

This gets me a result of "178440".

Is taking away two epoch date times away from each other valid? Or should i find the difference another way.

Comment: is the number of seconds the desired result?  or are you expecting days/months/years/etc ?

Comment: @BobNocraz I want to be able to add the result to another epoch date to work out a future date/time

Comment: it's perfectly fine as long as you want the time difference between two files.. and add that time difference to get future date ...

Comment: @SagarGuhe Thank you, the problem I am having now is when adding the result to an epoch date/time it sometimes gives odd years(5035) but sometimes it doesn't

Comment: PHP supports 10 digit epoch as I know so as long as the epoch is 10 digit it will not get you odd years...

Comment: @Kieron606 maybe you're adding it as a string, eg concatenating it?

Answer (score 0):

Try This May be help ful

```
<?php
$nextFile = '1452182820';
$firstFile = '1452004380';
$n =  date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$nextFile);
$f = date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$firstFile);
$Date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($n));
$Date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($f));
$datetime1 = new DateTime($Date1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($Date2);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```